# Ruby on Rails 2.3.8: Testing: Instance Variable Nil, when declared at top of class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing

So.. here is the top of my unit test file.

```
class ObjectTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  @user = -1
```

the test that fails (also the first one to use @user)

```
test "for detection of first content" do
  puts "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ #{@user.name}"
```

And this is the error I get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Now, I know that a number can't have any attributes like .name.. but I'm trying to solve a problem unrelated to trying to get the name of integers. The problem is that instance variable defined anywhere in my test file instantly turn to nil when na test begins -- as you can, the actual content of the test doesn't matter, the data inside @user is vanishing somehow. =\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class instance variables are a little odd, and I've not used them that much, but if I grok them correctly, they exist on the class itself and can only be accessed with the @ symbol in class methods - so you will have to access `@user` as `ObjectTest.user` or `self.class.user` when you are in instance methods, otherwise Ruby will look for the *instance instance variable* inside of instance methods. In other words, in a class function, you can refer to `@user`, but in an instance function, Ruby is looking for the @user variable on the *instance*. [here](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/299-Class-variables-vs-Class-instance-variables-in-Ruby) is a page that seems to demonstrate this behavior.

Since class variables (e.g. `@@user`) use a completely different syntax, they should not show this scope-colliding behavior - you can use `@@user` in both class and instance methods.